# writing in a user-defined .txt file

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-7

The basic syntax I use to write to a .txt file is this:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("data.txt", ios::trunc);
outfile<<"writing";
```

Now, supposing i were to let the user decide which file should be accessed, could it be done through a string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    ofstream myfile;
    string filename;
    char x;
    cin>>x;
    if (x==1)
        filename="data2.txt";
    myfile.open (filename, ios::trunc);
    myfile<<"writing";
    return 0;
}
```

I already tested this and it didn't work. My question is: is it possible to do such a thing? If yes, how? When i compile it, the error i get is the following:

```
undefined reference to 'std::basicofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
```

I can't understand what it is that's causing it.

Comment: Specify "didn't work." Didn't compile? If so, post the error. Didn't link? If so, post the error. Didn't behave as expected? If so, post both the expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: You're right, i am sorry. I edited it and also included the entire code.

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: Is this on Linux and are you compiling with gcc instead of g++?

Comment: This is on windows 7, i am using gnu gcc

Comment: Trace the path when `x == 5`.  The `filename` variable is empty.

Comment: The file is in the same folder as the .cpp file and the .exe file. I don't think that's what's causing it.

Comment: @VlassisFotis So how are you compiling this file?

Comment: I can't compile it. i get this error. Sorry if i am missing something obvious.

Comment: @VlassisFotis Why are you refusing to tell us 1) the command you're using to compile and 2) the complete error message you get when you do that?

Comment: @melpomene My being a noob is causing this. I am using the codeblocks platform because it's beginner-friendly. I select build and then build and run. After that i get this error, and yes it's the complete message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says it can't find `open` method that uses `std::string`.

Try this:

```
myfile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::trunc);
```

Some versions of C++ do not allow the `std::string` for `open` method, so you will have to use the `c_str()` method of `std::string`.

Comment: I was able to compile it now but for some reason the .txt file remains empty. Do you know what's causing that?

Comment: I recommend using a *debugger* to find out how your code is executing.

Comment: I was able to fix it :) . Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Actually, the declaration was found but the _definition_ wasn't, which suggests something of a broken toolchain to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `else` branch since if `x` isn't equal to `1` `open` has nothing to open.

Also you forgot to declare `ofstream myfile;` in your second snippet. Maybe that's the reason this doesn't work (it shouldn't even compile).

Comment: Sorry, i only included a piece of the code, now it's complete